# Is $A = \{ (x, \frac{1}{x}) : 0 < x \le 1 \} , $ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ? Yes/No

Tags: general-topology

Is $A = \{ (x, \frac{1}{x}) : 0 < x \le 1 \}$, compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

My attempt:  Yes, I take $f(x, y) = xy$ that is here $A$ is closed because is the inverse image of closed set that is $\{1\}$, by a continuous function.

Comment: You show correctly that it's closed. But "compact" needs more than just closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ were compact, its image by the  continuous map
\begin{align}
A&\longrightarrow \mathbf R, \\
\Bigl(x,\frac1x\Bigr)&\longmapsto x,
\end{align}
would be compact. However this image is the interval $(0,1]$, which is not closed in $\mathbf R$, thereby not compact.

Answer (score 4):

No. With your argument (which is correct but could be stated clearer) you have only shown that $A$ is **closed**. But it is not compact:

Because in $\Bbb R^n$ ($n \in \Bbb Z_+$), a subset is compact if and only if it is closed ***and bounded***. This is called the *Heine-Borel Theorem*. And here $A$, while closed, is definitely not bounded as obviously $\frac{1}{x}$ can take arbitrarily large values near $0$.

Answer (score 1):

A is closed but not bounded. Take the sequence $(\frac{1}{n},n)\in A$. It diverges to $\infty$ and hence, has no convergent subsequence. In conclusion, $A$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

Near zero,$\frac{1}{x}$ takes arbitrary large values, so the set is not bounded